# How to propogate build variant to libraries?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Before gradle 3, we could use

```
configurations {
  client1DevCompile
  ...
}
dependencies {
  client1DevCompile project(
    path: ':common',
    configuration: 'app1DevRelease'
  )
...
}
```

after gradle 3 it stated that build varian will be propagated automaticaly if both modules has same flavorDimensions and  productFlavors.
In my main module i have

```
flavorDimensions "environment"
productFlavors {
    prod {
        applicationId "package"
        dimension "environment"
    }

    qa {
        applicationId "package.qa"
        dimension "environment"
    }

    dev {
        applicationId "package.dev"
        dimension "environment"
    }
}

and in sub module i have
flavorDimensions "environment"
productFlavors {
    prod { dimension "environment" }
    qa { dimension "environment" }
    dev { dimension "environment" }
}
```

However when i select buildvarian for main module, it is not propagated
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sub-module change flavors like this:

```
flavorDimensions "environment"
productFlavors {
    prod { dimension "environment" }
    qa { dimension "environment" }
    dev { dimension "environment" }
}
```

And don't forget to add dependency to sub-module.

I have similar (better said more complex) situation and it works greatly. Here are my sample main/sub-module gradle flavors that works for me:

main:

```
flavorDimensions "brand", "mode"

productFlavors {
    // Brand
    a {
        dimension "brand"
        applicationIdSuffix ".a"
    }
    b{
        dimension "brand"
        applicationIdSuffix ".b"
    }

    // Demo-mode
    normal {
        dimension "mode"
        resValue "string", "demo_verion", ""
    }
    demo {
        dimension "mode"
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionNameSuffix "-demo"
        resValue "string", "demo_verion", "DEMO VERSION"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':submodulelib')
}
```

sub-module:

```
flavorDimensions "brand"

productFlavors {
    // Brand
    a{
        dimension "brand"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cFlags "-DA"
            }
        }
    }
    b{
        dimension "brand"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cFlags "-DB"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: added dimentions. however  flavors still not in sync, after i change main module to qa, dev module stays in dev

Comment: @Yarh have you tried to change main flavor again from build variant menu? whenever I change product flavor dimensions, android studio does not detect it until I try to change app's build variant.

Comment: @Yarh I added a sample from my working main/sub-module.

Comment: yep, i changin only main module flavor from build variant menu.

Comment: @Yarh What I posted is working for me. if you can please add most of main and sub-module gradle files(just remove important parts).